# How to pass total number of classes preceding an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
<script>
function Answered(str) {
   var script = document.getElementsByClassName('Answered')[str];
   if(script!==null) {script.setAttribute("style", "");}
}
</script>

<span class=Answered style="background-color: #FFBED1">Is the sky blue?</span><br>
<select name="SkyBlue" onchange="Answered(0)">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select><br>
<br>

<span class=Answered style="background-color: #FFBED1">How old are you?</span><br>
<input name=Age onchange="Answered(1)"><br>
<br>

<span class=Answered style="background-color: #FFBED1">Is grass green?</span><br>
<select name="GrassGreen" onchange="Answered(2)">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select><br>
```

I would like to replace "Answered(0)", "Answered(1)", "Answered(2)" with something like "Answered(classes == 'Answered' preceding this element)" so as elements get moved around or inserted, the numbering doesn't have to be redone.

Comment: what is your goal for this?  You  only want the background for the span to be red for unanswered inputs?  What should happen should someone unanswer a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated!

As i see the comments realised the earlier answer had some bugs. So, here it is now been updated to look for actual element in the DOM Tree.

Instead pass `this`:

```js
function Answered(el) {
  var isSpan = el.previousElementSibling;
  var elem = checkPrev(el);
  if (el.value === "") {
    return false;
  }
  if (isSpan.nodeName === "SPAN") {
    isSpan.setAttribute("style", "");
  }

  function checkPrev(currElem) {
    if (currElem.previousElementSibling.nodeName !== 'SPAN') {
      Answered(currElem.previousElementSibling)
    } else {
      return currElem.previousElementSibling;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<span class=Answered style="background-color: #FFBED1">Is the sky blue?</span>
<br>
<select name="SkyBlue" onchange="Answered(this)">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<span class=Answered style="background-color: #FFBED1">How old are you?</span>
<br>
<input name=Age onchange="Answered(this)">
<br>
<br>

<span class=Answered style="background-color: #FFBED1">Is grass green?</span>
<br>
<select name="GrassGreen" onchange="Answered(this)">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<br>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6phtb9h1/)

Comment: Looks like they are trying to set the style on the span and not the select though

Comment: I don't think this will work since the elements arent inside of the spans that I'm trying to edit.

Comment: there's a `br` element in between the two elements you should account for or does previousElementSibling skip `br`?

Comment: I've tried your latest update and it seems to lock up.

Comment: the break; doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: I picked this since the mention of .previousElementSibling; is what led to me posting my end solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
<script>
function Answered(str) {
var span = document.getElementsByName(str)[0].previousElementSibling;
span.setAttribute("style", "");
}
</script>

<span class=Answered style="background-color: #FFBED1">Is the sky blue?<br></span>
<select name="SkyBlue" onchange="Answered(this.name)">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select><br>
<br>
<span class=Answered style="background-color: #FFBED1">How old are you?<br></span>
<input name=Age onchange="Answered(this.name)"><br>
<br>
<span class=Answered style="background-color: #FFBED1">Is grass green?<br></span>
<select name="GrassGreen" onchange="Answered(this.name)">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select><br>
```

I moved the br tags to be inside the spans and used this.name to identify my elements without having to add id's.

Edit: Since someone asked what to do if someone unanswers a question:

```
function Answered(str,value) {
var span = document.getElementsByName(str)[0].previousElementSibling;
span.setAttribute("style", "");
if(value.length<1) {span.style.backgroundColor="#FFBED1";}
}
```

and the call to the function:

```
<select name="SkyBlue" onchange="Answered(this.name,this.value)">
```

and if you want to use 'this' instead:

```
<script>
function Answered(element) {
element.previousElementSibling.setAttribute("style", "");
if(element.value.length<1) {element.previousElementSibling.style.backgroundColor="#FFBED1";}
}
</script>

<span class=Answered style="background-color: #FFBED1">Is the sky blue?<br></span>
<select name="SkyBlue" onchange="Answered(this)">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select><br>
<br>
<span class=Answered style="background-color: #FFBED1">How old are you?<br></span>
<input name=Age onchange="Answered(this)"><br>
<br>
<span class=Answered style="background-color: #FFBED1">Is grass green?<br></span>
<select name="GrassGreen" onchange="Answered(this)">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select><br>
```

Comment: If I were you i'd pass `this` object into the function instead.  Then you have access to `this` and can do `this.previousElementSibling` and `this.value` inside the function so you don't have to get the element again

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery - check all your answers after each input changes and change background accordingly

```
$(function() {
  $(':input').on('change', function() { // on any input changed 
    $('.Answered')
       .css('background-color','#FFBED1') // change color to red
       .filter(function(){  // filter out spans that have inputs with a value
             return $.trim($(this).nextAll(':input:first').val()) !== '';
             // I trimmed the value to account for blank answers
       }).css('background-color',''); // remove background color from spans with answers
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s3yy0wor/)